# Apache URL rewrite (mod_rewrite) and uuid

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, uuid

I want to rewrite the following URL in apache:

```
abc.php?id=1234&token=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

where `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx` is a V4 UUID

I have tried to make rewrite rule like:

```
RewriteRule  ^/ABC/([0-9]+)$/^([0-9a-fA-F]){8}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){12}.([0-1]){1}/ /abc.php?id=$1&token=$2
```

but it seems that it's not really working.

I think i dun need a regex that exactly represent a V4 UUID but just simple regex to represent the Characters and hyphen in the UUID string, anybody has good idea in apache regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
RewriteRule ^/ABC/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ abc.php?id=$1&token=$2
```

If you want to further validate the token, it would be better to do so in PHP, seeing as that's its intended use.

Comment: i feel like this could be better done using rewriterule - 36 character uuid etc `[A-z0-9\-]{36}`